# Grails : Error in run the application

Tags: grails

I have tried to run grails application but it shows the below error

> Problem updating profiles from origin git repository (Use --stacktrace
>   to see the full trace)

someone pls help me.

Comment: Error looks like a problem with a network connection. Do you have any proxies? Does it also occur if you connect via VPN? Which version of Grails do you use?

Comment: Call me crazy, but I'll bet you would see more information if you used `--stacktrace to see the full trace`

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue mainly because of network issues. Run "Grails Dependencies" you will see the exact error. Which is the file which it is not able to download and what is the reason will be shown.

Comment: i have tried --stacktrace it shows below error,                                           Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Can we discuss regarding the same over communicator(Lync) @santosh_a06@infosys.com or santosh.anantharamaiah@gmail.com

Comment: thanks for your reply . I have sent a mail to you regarding above issue.